# Help with ESP32-CAM "AI THINKER" module

Tags: wifi, esp32, web-server, error

I'm trying to make a RC car (with a surveillance camera if possible, using the web-cam code that comes with the ESP library) using a ESP-32 CAM as a wifi module to control the car using my computer. Problem is that I keep getting the "invalid head of packet" error whenever I try uploading anything. I've tried holding the boot button as I upload and I cannot use the capacitor simply because I don't have it and don't want to buy it and spend time getting it. I also have the GPIO0 pin connected to GND during the uploading process. Any other ways to get it working? My car consists of 2 DC motors powering only the back two wheels and a servo that steers the front wheels, and I want to use the ESP32-CAM to connect to wifi to connect to a webserver from my pc to control the car.

Comment: I suspect that the power supply you used to power the ESP-32 can't provide the sufficient current.

Comment: You don’t need a capacitor and you don’t need to hold any buttons while uploading, just connect GPIO0 to ground, +3.3V power to your ESP32Cam’s +3.3V input, ground from the power supply/USB to Serial to ESP32 ground, Serial TX to ESP32 RX and Serial RX to ESP32 TX. The entire procedure is [outlined very clearly here](https://dronebotworkshop.com/esp32-cam-intro/). What kind of USB-to-Serial are you using?

Comment: @StarCat, I tried what you said but now I'm getting the "Timed out waiting for packet header" error.